# Concatenate Query Params as string - Angular- Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate all the query params string that I have into a one final query including all params but I keep getting this result :

```
_filter=0=((startDate=ge=2019-09-30T22:00:00.000Z);(endDate=le=2019-10- 
03T22:00:00.000Z));1= 
(category=eq=Warning,category=eq=Error);&_limit=50&_sort=asc
```

with the annoying 0=, 1=, 2=, ....

The expected result is to be like that :

```
_filter=((startDate=ge=2019-10-06T12:39:05.000Z;endDate=le=2019-10- 
07T23:59:59.999Z);(category=eq=ALERT,category=eq=META))"
```

Here is my code:

```
generateQueryString(obj: any) {
     let query = [];
     if (obj.startDate && obj.endDate) {
       query = query.concat(this.buildDateQueryString(obj.startDate, obj.endDate)
      );
     }
     if (obj.category) {
       query = query.concat(this.buildCategoryQueryString(obj.category));
     } 
    return query;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact question: If you want to add queries to your initial empty query set, you can use "push". If you want to concatenate strings you can consider starting with `query = ""` instead of `query = {}`

Comment: I already dit both of that and same error message: "Property 'concat' or 'push' does not exist on type '{}'" :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Let us assume you want pass some data like

```
const userData = {
    firstName: 'Arpit',
    lastName: 'Patel'
}
```

2. You can pass this object into Query Params like this.

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/details'], { queryParams: { user: JSON.stringify(userData) } });
```

3. Then extract this Object in next component which is called as below.

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const user= JSON.parse(params.user);
      console.log(user);
});
```

4. This will result in JSON object. You can access it directly.